# Can I set the Text Layout for a team site page using code?

Tags: layouts

Most people would likely answer a question like this by saying to look at Page Layouts but they are no good to me. I already have custom Page Layouts for use in a publishing page but what I want to do is to set a Text Layout using code.

When I create a new team site with the wiki homepage feature enabled I can view a page and edit a page at SitePages/Home.aspx. In the ribbon there is an option called 'Text Layouts'. I can select something such as "3 columns with header". I have searched everywhere for how I can set this in code but have found nothing.

Can anyone help with this or even help with creating custom Text Layouts?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really supported but seems someone has made a solution at [Create web part pages with custom layouts in SharePoint 2010](http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/08/create-web-part-pages-with-custom.html)

Comment: Thanks - I will have a look. It doesn't sound like it is possible to programmatically add webparts via code to wiki pages as well as changing the Text Layout.